# Form booleanfield does not appear in request.POST data

Tags: django, django-forms

I tried printing out all (key,value) pairs in a `request.POST` to extract the form data. I notice that a BooleanField, if not checked (i.e. set to `True`), is not included in `request.POST`. This is true even if the BooleanField is set with `required=True`.

Is it possible to force the (key,pair) to be sent? For example, in this form below, if `applied` field is not checked when rendered, `request.POST` should still include `applied off`? When `applied` is checked, `request.POST` includes `applied on`. But without being checked, `applied` is not part of `request.POST` data.

```
class ItemModifierForm(forms.Form):
     applied= forms.BooleanField(label='Trait A', required=True)
```

Comment: Include your views.py where you are calling this form and processing it.

Comment: @iklinac Thanks. I see. That's quite a pain.